# Error during generating the Doxygen document

Tags: doxygen

I got this problem during generating the Doxygen document:

```
Problems running dot: exit code=127, command='dot', arguments='"/home/AAA/src/html/ABC_8hpp__incl.dot" -Tpng -o "/home/AAA/src/html/ABC_8hpp__incl.png" -Tcmapx -o "/home/AAA/src/html/ABC_8hpp__incl.map"'
sh: dot: not found
```

Gave the output is like this for the constructor:

```
{
  namespace applicationTest
  {
```

Has anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have dot installed on the machine? Do you want to use it to generate the graphs?

If not, set the `HAVE_DOT` option to "no".

If yes, make sure dot is in the path, or set its location with the `DOT_PATH` option.

Comment: Hi, I set both HAVE_DOT and DOT_PATH to no but it does not work... Thanks

Comment: including it in your environment variables ( PATH:=..... ) and then leave it blank in the config file is what Eric meant.  I noticed that on some machines the bash and sh: commands fail regardless of what you put in the config file.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install graphviz`

Comment: @Polluks Thanks installed it, and now it works.